# iTunes Transporter error: Could not resolve module: com.apple.transporter.starter

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, itmstransporter

When uploading our apps (via `fastlane`), iTMSTransporter suddenly started failing with the following:

```
[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Application.main(Application.java:947)

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter] Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.apple.transporter.starter [20]

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.annotation; version="[3.0.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.transporter.launcher.asu; version="[1.0.0,2.0.0)"

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter] 

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:440)

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:459)

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase2.bootstrapBundles(BootstrapperPhase2.java:321)

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase2.start(BootstrapperPhase2.java:153)

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase1.startOSGiFramework(BootstrapperPhase1.java:319)

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase1.bootstrap(BootstrapperPhase1.java:99)

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   at com.apple.transporter.bootstrap.BootstrapperPhase1.bootstrap(BootstrapperPhase1.java:59)

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   at com.apple.transporter.launcher.Launcher.launchBootstrapper(Launcher.java:37)

[14:30:51]: [iTMSTransporter]   ... 6 more

[14:30:51]: iTunes Transporter output above ^
[14:30:51]: The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
```

This happened using Xcode 13.2.1, right after upgrading from Xcode 12.4

Answer (score 2):

Delete the folder `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.amp.itmstransporter` and try again.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/129378?answerId=419847022#419847022